# Received HTTP status code [401] with message "{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}" when getting temporary credentials

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, laravel-8

I am using laravel/socialite package.

I am trying to use the twitter login API but I am getting this error when getting temporary credentials:

> Received HTTP status code [401] with message "{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}"

```php
// config/services.php
'twitter' => [
    'client_id' => env('TWITTER_APP_API_KEY'),
    'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_APP_API_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('TWITTER_APP_CALLBACK'),
],
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class SocialController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function callback($provider)
    {
       $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

       return (array)$user;
    }
}
```

```php
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/redirect/{provider}', [SocialController::class, 'redirect']);
Route::get('{provider}/callback', [SocialController::class, 'callback']);
```

```
// .env
TWITTER_APP_API_KEY=MY_TWITTER_APP_API_KEY
TWITTER_APP_API_SECRET=MY_TWITTER_APP_API_SECRET
TWITTER_APP_CALLBACK=http://mywebsite.test/twitter/callback
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem after reading laravel/socailite document

i don`t need to add the following code

```
//config/app.php

....
....
'providers' => [
    ....
    ....
    Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    ....
    ....
    'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
],
....
....
```

all i need to do

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

then the following steps:

```
# install
composer require socialiteproviders/twitter

# register
protected $listen = [
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        'SocialiteProviders\Twitter\TwitterExtendSocialite@handle'
    ],
];

# configure
'twitter' => [
    'client_id' => env('TWITTER_KEY'),
    'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI'),
]

# start building
return Socialite::driver('twitter')->redirect();
```

you can install any socialite provider form here: https://socialiteproviders.com/

Answer (score 3):

I found out that I had been using oauth 2 client id and client secret in my configuration of twitter application. Please make sure you are using the credentials (API Key and Secret) from "Consumer Keys" section on twitter app settings. The API Key and Secret under "Consumer Keys" are client id and client secret respectively for oauth 1.